# Worker killed running Tensorflow on Google App Engine flexible

Tags: tensorflow, google-app-engine, flask

I am attempting to use Tensorflow to predict from a model on Google App Engine. Session seems to start up and run for a couple of seconds before the worker is killed / booted.

> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
>
> tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2200000000 Hz
>
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x572b370 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
>
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): ,
>
> tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set. If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU. To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
>
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 154389504 exceeds 10% of system memory.
>
> [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25

Is there some configuration I may have not set? App is running using Flask / Gunicorn.

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: Have you tried maxing out memory?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know the specifics of the reason without knowing your app.yaml or were the app is located, nevertheless, it seems that you are trying to run it in an instance with incompatible CPU. I would recommend you to change the instance CPU in your [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) to make sure that the CPU matches your needs.

I hope you find this information useful.